# Unexplained ArrayStoreException - Code or Configuration Issue

Tags: java, configuration, classpath, classloader, environment

I am trying to debug an application that is working properly when tested locally on a Windows XP machine (version 5.1 build 2600 Service Pack 3) through Websphere Platform 6.1 running java version 1.5.

This application is throwing an ArrayStoreException when it is deployed to UNIX servers (SunOS, version 5.10) running java version 1.5.0_24.

I am leaning towards this being an environment configuration issue, but (other than it working locally) I can't seem to confirm that it's a configuration issue.

**Below are the *log messages*** that were added to the code to troubleshoot. As noted in the logs, the code is trying to add a *Profile* object to an Array of type *Profile*. I don't see why that wouldn't be working.

CollectionUtility.searchMapmsg=ZZZZZ Caught ArrayStoreException ZZZZZ

CollectionUtility.searchMap|msg=ZZZZZ Unable to add list item to Array of type [Lcom.process.im.profile.impl.Profile; ZZZZZ

CollectionUtility.searchMap|msg=ZZZZZ List[0] is class com.process.im.profile.impl.Profile, toString()=com.process.im.profile.impl.Profile mId=4, mLongName=ccounting ZZZZZ

**Below is the *java code*** that is producing the error

```
public static Object[] searchMap(Map m, Object[] keys, Object[] a)
{
    if (keys != null && a != null)
    {
        List<Object> l = new ArrayList<Object>(keys.length);

        searchMap(m, keys, l, true, null);

        try
        {
            a = l.toArray(a);

        }
        catch (ArrayStoreException eArrayStore)
        {
            Log.warning("CollectionUtility.searchMap", "ZZZZZ Caught ArrayStoreException ZZZZZ", 0);

            if(l==null)
            {
                Log.warning("CollectionUtility.searchMap", "ZZZZZ Core CollectionUtility ZZZZZ null list.", 0);
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i=0; i<l.size(); i++)
                {
                    Object bug = l.get(i);

                    if(bug==null)
                    {
                        Log.warning("CollectionUtility.searchMap", "ZZZZZ List[" + i + "] is null ZZZZZ", 0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (a!=null && !a.getClass().getName().equals(bug.getClass().getName()))
                        {
                            Log.warning("CollectionUtility.searchMap", "ZZZZZ Unable to add list item to Array of type " + a.getClass().getName() + " ZZZZZ", 0);

                            Log.warning("CollectionUtility.searchMap", "ZZZZZ List[" + i + "] is class " + bug.getClass().getName() + ", toString()=" + bug.toString() + " ZZZZZ", 0);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            throw eArrayStore;

        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

I know I may be missing something simple, but I'm not sure what to check next.  If any of you have any ideas, please let me know.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: 1. Changing method argument value ( a = l.toArray(a);) is not a good idea.
2. Would you mind posting the searchMap(m, keys, l, true, null) code?

Comment: I don't know about you but... after reading this code a few times, I think the answer is so obvious that I can't even see it... Let me ask you this: does the parameter `a` contain any null values ? Also, I am very sure that this `a.getClass().getName().equals(bug.getClass().getName())` always returns `false` because an `Object` is not the same as an `Object[]`.

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me!  It is greatly appreciated.  I agree that the comparing one element from the list to a type of array will never be equal so the check for null would have been sufficient to display the logs.  I still don't know why an ArrayStoreException is being thrown, but I did find out that this code isn't causing problems on all of our UNIX servers.  It is only showing up in our UNIX environments that are using load balanced servers.  I'm going to see if I can find out more.  Please let me know if you have run into something like this before.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one, you are comparing the class of an Object array to an Object. I'm pretty sure thats not what you are intending to do.